# Meteor as a client-side only framework (with a custom back-end)

Tags: meteor, ddp

I'd like to use Meteor as a client-side only framework, and make it connect to my backend over DDP.

What is the best way to get a hold of the client-side libraries? Is there a stand alone distribution for the client-side of the framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is stand-alone [Blaze](http://meteor.github.io/blaze/) which is Meteor's front-end rendering engine. The current distribution is a bit dated and includes a lot of things you might not need: minimongo, deps, jquery, underscore.

If you want to assemble a set of Meteor packages manually, you can follow this:

```
$ meteor create dummy-app
$ cd dummy-app
$ meteor add iron:router percolate:momentum # ... put packages you want to use here
$ meteor build ../build --directory
$ cd ../build/bundle/programs/web.browser
$ # grab js and css here
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw the Blaze distribution, but it seems to be missing the parts that speak DDP as far as I can tell. The manual way works well enough though.